# Liferay session.timeout.redirect.on.expire won't work

Tags: java, redirect, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I wanted my site to redirect to the login page after the session expire. So i set the session.timeout.redirect.on.expire=true and everything works fine only when i use the classic liferay theme. The problem is when i change to my custom theme the redirect simply doesn't work. Do you know what could cause this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Provide the Liferay version and configuration detail.Also check the default.logout.page.path this property.

Comment: I'm using liferay 6.2 and the only session configurations are session.timeout.redirect.on.expire=true
session.timeout.warning=0
session.timeout.auto.extend=false

Comment: Other way around is you can create simple a jsp hook which override docroot/html/common/themes/session_timeout.jspf just replace redirectional logic to c/portal/logout on the basis of your need

Comment: How can i do that replacement? I don't know how to work with the <aui:script use="liferay-session">